# Angle between vector and axis

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to make some data work for Malus Law with 3 polarizers (don't worry, my question is about geometry, not physics), and I think I should know this but I'm loosing my mind at this point.

Let's say we have a vector $v$ in two dimensions making an angle $\theta$ with the $Y$ axis, then what's the expresion for the angle with the $X$ axis?

I was thinking about adding something to $\theta$, but I believe that doesn't work for a domain $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Is this in two dimensions or three?

Comment: Two dimensions, I will edit my question.

Comment: If you want the angle to lie in a certain range, you’ll almost certainly have to perform some normalization after the arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Do this using coordinates:

$x = ||v||\sin(\theta)$

$y = ||v||\cos(\theta)$

Then your angle with the x Axis is $\phi = atan2(y, x)$ where atan2 is the arc tangent corrected for the quadrant by considering the sign of x and y.